# Expand the values in the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df1 that looks like :

```
F_Date  Booking_Date    col r_count
01/09/2019  02/08/2019  70  22
01/09/2019  03/08/2019  73  12
01/09/2019  04/08/2019  76  9
01/09/2019  06/08/2019  79  6
01/09/2019  09/08/2019  82  5
01/09/2019  10/08/2019  86  4
01/09/2019  11/08/2019  89  4
01/09/2019  12/08/2019  93  4
01/09/2019  13/08/2019  97  4
01/09/2019  14/08/2019  101 4
01/09/2019  15/08/2019  106 3
01/09/2019  16/08/2019  110 3
01/09/2019  17/08/2019  115 4
```

I want to create a new dataframe df2 such that :

each row in df1 is to be expanded according to r_count for example, for 1st entry, new dataframe would have 22 values.

a New column value_1, to be created such that, sum of all the values of column value_1 totals to be equal to 'col' column. for example, 1st row needs to be expanded to 22 entries and sum of value_1 for all 22 entries needs to be 70(value in col is 70).

**I dont want to divide the col equally and rather should be randomly divided. All other column remain the same in the new dataframe**

**Expected Output dataframe columns**

```
F_Date  Booking_Date    col r_count  value_1
```

Can anyone help with the same.

Thanks

Comment: I think we need more details. The first row that you're hoping to split into 22 rows, am I right in saying the 22 values in the value_1 column should add to 70 and the 22 values should be random? Can those values be negative? Are you looking for just integers?

Comment: @OD1995 Yes the value should be random and cannot take negative values. We are just looking at integer values in column value_1

Comment: And the random values can fall into any range?

Comment: @OD1995, yes but sum should be equal to total col value.